# Creating column names for the output of `Vectorize()` in R?

Tags: r, function, vectorization

I was wondering if there is a way to create the two *column names* `x1` and `x2` for the output *(see picture below)* of the following `Vectorize` `R` function:

```
normal <- Vectorize(function(n){

     x <- rnorm(n)
  mean <- mean(x)
    sd <- sd(x)

  return(c(mean = mean, sd = sd))
})
# Example of use:
normal(n = c(1e2, 1e3))
```

[image]

Comment: You can wrap in data.frame() to get auto-names X1 and X2.

Comment: @Frank, would you mind showing this, try for example: `return(data.frame(mean = mean, sd = sd))` and that doesn't help. Or you may mean something else?

Comment: Do `data.frame(normal(n = c(1e2, 1e3)))`

Comment: @Renu, I wish I could use `data.frame(normal(n = c(1e2, 1e3)))` inside the function?

Comment: Why? It won't be any faster. You can create a new function and wrap it around what you're currently calling `normal`.

Comment: I think you can do it inside the function. `return(data.frame(c(mean = mean, sd = sd)))` ... not tested, but it seems to be the same. If somehow it doesn't work, you can make a wrapper function. `newnormal = function(...) data.frame(normal(...))` ? (The three dots are literally part of the code, not placeholder pseudocode, btw.)

Comment: @Frank, would mind showing your last suggestion in `R` code?

Comment: I meant that that is R code. One line is `newnormal = function(...) data.frame(normal(...))` to define the function. Then you can test it with `newnormal(n = c(1e2, 1e3))`

Comment: @Frank, oh I see, but in case instead of `x1` other names is desired I guess your solution doesn't work. I wish I could use `colnames(x) <- paste0('x', 1:length(x))` or the like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just name your input vector. Since `USE.NAMES` is `TRUE` by default, the names carry through to the output.

```
normal(n = c(X1 = 1e2, X2 = 1e3))
```

Or you can set the names inside your function

```
normal <- function(x){
  if(is.null(names(x))) names(x) <- paste0('x', 1:length(x))
  fun <- Vectorize(
          function(n){
              x     <- rnorm(n)
              mean  <- mean(x)
              sd    <- sd(x)
              return(c(mean = mean, sd = sd))
          }
          )
  fun(x)
}


# Example of use:
normal(c(1e2, 1e3))
```

Comment: Thanks, but we can't have this INSIDE the function? My goal is to achieve this inside the function. That is, user won't need to provide `X1` and `X2`.

Comment: @rnorouzian But what about when your user *does* provide a named vector?  Won't they expect the output to have the same names?  Guessing what your user will want can lead to code that's complicated for the maintainer and surprising for the users.

Comment: @NathanWerth, that's not the issue here. I simply want the column names to be what I want. Now, since user can use as many `n` elements as s/he wants, I want the column names have an numeric attachment to them, such as `r1, . . ., ri`.